# Adding libraries to a C compiler

Tags: c, gcc

I use *Linux* and compile the C programs using *inbuilt gcc compiler*. While creating a program that is for the Windows platform I had to use certain predefined functions listed in `<windows.h>`. Similarly there are other functions whose libraries are not predefined in **GCC** compiler.
So how to add those customized libraries to the C compiler in Linux?

Comment: Those are just header files; there's usually significant libraries that also go with them.  And, as you are finding, each platform offers its own APIs in headers and libraries.  So you will need to research and find the appropriate equivalent implementations (if they exist) on the platforms you're building for.

Comment: Uhhh, you are trying to compile a program on *Linux*, which uses the *Windows.h* header? It isn't going to work.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of writing portable software.  There are whole libraries of code that simulate (parts of) the Windows API on Unix derivatives.  There are also a lot of API calls available for Unix that are not available on Windows.  Choosing how to create common functionality is one of the tricky aspects of making software work on both Windows and Unix (where I regard Linux as a variant of Unix — you can substitute Linux where I say Unix if you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean static libraries when you say libraries. You can include the library file path in your gcc command so that gcc can link your library or you can create a makefile and use 'make'. if you don't know how to use 'make' I recomend you to learn it.